# comparing different rows with same column in data frame python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, dataframe, numpy

i have two dataframes .

```
Dataframe # 1 input :
abc.json.gz
cde.json.gz
efg.json.gz

#dataframe 1

file_val = pd.DataFrame(val, columns=['filename']) # dataframe 1

Dataframe # 2 input :
ghi.json.gz
abc.json.gz
cde.json.gz
mno.json.gz
xyz.json.gz

#dataframe 2

rds_rcd = pd.read_sql_query('''select filename from tablename where cast(event_date as date) = '{0}' '''.format(self.timestr), conn) 

Below code to check if there are any common records between both dataframe # 1 and daframe # 2

file_val['status'] = np.where(file_val['filename'].values != rds_rcd['filename'].values, 'False', 'True')
```

Both of the above dataframes have same column(filename), but different no# of records.

***Question :*** Even though the "abc.json.gz" and "cde.json.gz" exist in both the dataframes  , see the value as 'False' for all records.

```
   filename    status                                            
0  abc.json.gz  False
1  cde.json.gz  False
```

Any suggestions, would be great.

Comment: Please clarify what specifically you are looking for help in doing.  To clarify, provide a specific question, include sample input data, the code you have written and what you expect as output.  Please review Jon Skeet's excellent blog post [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for guidance in updating your question.  For a more detailed tutorial on asking a good question see Eric S. Raymond's site [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: Thankyou for the blog post, hope so i formatted it proper way.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have 2 dataframes df1 and df2 like:

```
df1:
    filename
0   abc.json.gz
1   cde.json.gz
2   efg.json.gz
```

and

```
df2:  
    filename
0   ghi.json.gz
1   abc.json.gz
2   cde.json.gz
3   mno.json.gz
4   xyz.json.gz
```

You can find the common set of filenames with:

```
common_files = set(df1['filename'].to_list()).intersection(set(df2['filename'].to_list()))
```

This yields:

```
{'abc.json.gz', 'cde.json.gz'}
```

Comment: great, but what was wrong with my    file_val['status'] = np.where(file_val['filename'].values != rds_rcd['filename'].values, 'False', 'True') . as would like to have "status" as seperate column for all matching as "True" or else "False".

Comment: I am not expert on the np.where function, but I would use this function to find the rows in either file that satisfy a condition.  So in your case, the result of ```file_val['filename'].values``` is a Pandas Series of the file names from file_val, and the result of ```rds_rcd['filename'].values``` is a Series of file names from rds_rcd.  You are then comparing the first item in the file_val series  against the first item in the rcd_val series, if Not = setting the result to False, else True.  Since the names are not aligned between the two series your are always getting False.